# Some unwanted UIImageViews disappear while trying to set them as borders of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

What I am trying to do is to replace borders(solid lines by default, of course) by small dots. I want the size of the dots to be 6 by 6.

Making borders invisible is a simple thing to do; I just set separators as 'None' in the attribute inspector.

But there was no field to set images or other objects as separators. To solve this problem, I splitted the dot into up and down pieces, assigned them in UIImageViews, and located the upper one on the bottom and the lower one on the top.

Then in the **function tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)**, I got the lower image in the first row and the upper image in the last row invisible.

What make the problem is that some unwanted dots disappear, while the dots I intended to change are properly gone away. Furthermore they come back or go away when the `tableView` is scrolled. The codes and the screenshot are below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "reuseIdentifier"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyListTableViewCell

    //each element in datas[] has lowercase alphabets, a from q.
    let array = datas[indexPath.row]

    //data is a UIButton, which is the only component in each row besided those dots
    cell.data.setTitle(array, forState: .Normal)

    //this is where I typed to handle the unwanted dots on the very top and bottom
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        cell.lowerHalf.hidden = true
    }
    else if indexPath.row == datas.count - 1{
        cell.upperHalf.hidden = true
    }
    ///////////////////

    return cell
}
```

[image]

When I scrolled `tableView` up and down side, it changed to this:

[image]

What makes the dots which shouldn't disappear go away? Or is their a better way to set images as borders?

+In the way iSashok suggested, things didn't change unfortunately. I applied this code right after the declaration; and then I moved to right before the return statement. Both did not work.

```
cell.clipsToBound = false
```

Comment: for your more info, The reason why I didn't use a full dot is that the UIButton will not be centered vertically in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cell is getting reuse so you need to change your `if` condition of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.lowerHalf.hidden = true
    cell.upperHalf.hidden = false
}
else if indexPath.row == datas.count - 1{
    cell.lowerHalf.hidden = false
    cell.upperHalf.hidden = true
}
else {
    cell.lowerHalf.hidden = false
    cell.upperHalf.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: Hey you're the man. I don't know why I did not add the last block of codes to set the other half-dots visible.

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify for your cell `clipsToBounds` property in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

like below

```
cell.clipsToBounds = false;
```

and for `contentView` the same

```
cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = false;
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. I took a screenshot but didn't upload to the edited post because it's the same as before.

Comment: add for `contentView` the same `cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = false;`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use **UITableViewHeaderFooterView**? Simply create your view with that dot image in centre and return that view from **viewForFooterInSection.**